Missing colcon-argcomplete.bash in Jazzy release — Is this an oversight or an intentional change?
In the Humble release of Colcon, the file colcon-argcomplete.bash is present and works perfectly for enabling Bash auto-completion. However, in the Jazzy release, I noticed that this file is missing from the usual location:
/usr/share/colcon_argcomplete/hook/colcon-argcomplete.bash

Was this an intentional change in Jazzy, or is it a bug that the file is missing? If it’s intentional, are there any plans to restore it, or is there an alternative way to enable auto-completion in Jazzy? or it is placed in a different location?
Thanks in advance for the help!
